# Why is Wordpress creating a giant error_log file?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have a small Wordpress website hosted on my shared Hostgator server. I wasn't paying much attention to it, because the website is working fine, until recently when I noticed a ~40GB error log file in the root folder. I wasn't able to open the file so I delete it and waited for the file to show up again. Few seconds later the file was there again with this line inside:

> [07-Nov-2016 04:26:22] WordPress database error DELETE command denied to user 'HIDDEN_DATABASE_NAME'@'localhost' for table 'sv_options' for query DELETE FROM `sv_options` WHERE `option_name` = '_transient_doing_cron' made by delete_transient, delete_option

I've run repair and optimize in the phpMyAdmin, but this line is still being added into the file approximately every 2 minutes. How should I find what's causing this error? I'm not an expert but I can find my way around cPanel.

Comment: It is pretty self explained... `database error DELETE command denied to user 'HIDDEN_DATABASE_NAME'@'localhost'` i.e. the user which trying to execute DELETE query doesn't have permissions to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error it seems that mysql user which is trying to perform `DELETE` doesn't have permission to do that. What you have to do is to give permission to this user, like:

```
grant all privileges on mydb.* to myuser@'%' identified by 'mypasswd';
grant all privileges on mydb.* to myuser@localhost identified by 'mypasswd';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

This should stop adding errors to your log. More references about [MySQL grant and privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)

You can see all privileges for the user in phpmyadmin also with the following sql

```
show grants for myuser@'localhost';
```

**NOTE:** Above statements will give ALL privileges to one user which from security point of view isn't good idea. Since the error is about `DELETE` you can give delete privileges only to user ( or select, update, insert if needed also )

```
GRANT DELETE ON mydb.* to myuser@'%' identified by 'mypasswd';
```

Comment: I would never grant all privileges, only the ones which are needed. A application should not have the privilege to create a user or change permission.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I agree. I would not do this also and I will make a note to my answer.

Comment: Before I try this, is there a way to find what process is trying to execute delete? I'm reluctant to grant this privilege without knowing why is this happening.

Comment: I would start from cronjobs or some automated tasks. Seems like the operation is running non stop.. check them. Also check plugins..